# Django REST Framework multiple update performance issues

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    parent  = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel)
    a_field = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    # some more fields
```

And a Django REST Framework serializer:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = MyModel
```

When updating multiple items using the following code, the performance of the update is very poor, especially if the `MyModel` contains many records (in my case ~30K).

```
updated_objects = [...] # an array of serialized MyModel instances
existing_objects = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in = [obj['id'] for obj in updated_objects])
s = MyModelSerializer(existing_objects, data = updated_objects, many = True)
s.is_valid()
s.save()
```

After debugging the code I found out that 5 SQL queries are executed for every updated item:

- one for resolving the `parent` field to a `ParentModel` instance.
- 3 during the `full_clean` function of the item, probably for validating the items' fields.
- one for actually updating the item

Is there a way to improve the performance of bulk updates, for example caching the resolved `ParentModel` instances? Updating 50 rows in a table of 30K takes more than 20 seconds.